# How to free up Port using PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, port

I am using PHP sockets to receive data on the TCP/IP level, I am able to do this with the current code but it seems that after some time the socket server crashes and the port becomes useless.

When this happens I cannot receive data through this port anymore, and the data i'm receiving is coming from a device, which are disbursed across multiple locations. I cannot then manually change the port to get this up and running again.

I am wondering if there is a way to end the process/unblock the port and start the process again upon crashing?

```
<?php

require_once("SocketServer.php"); // Include the File
$server = new SocketServer("XX.XXX.XX.XX",3030); // Create a Server binding to the given ip address and listen to port XXXX for connections
$server->max_clients = 10; // Allow no more than 10 people to connect at a time
$server->hook("CONNECT","handle_connect"); // Run handle_connect every time someone connects
$server->hook("INPUT","handle_input"); // Run handle_input whenever text is sent to the server
$server->infinite_loop(); // Run Server Code Until Process is terminated.


function handle_connect(&$server,&$client,$input)
{
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String? ","");
}
function handle_input(&$server,&$client,$input)
{
    // You probably want to sanitize your inputs here
    $trim = trim($input); // Trim the input, Remove Line Endings and Extra Whitespace.
      $file_p = dirname(__FILE__) . '/input.json';
      $fp = fopen($file_p,"wb");
      fwrite($fp,$trim);
      fclose($fp);


    if(strtolower($trim) == "quit") // User Wants to quit the server
    {
        SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"Oh... Goodbye..."); // Give the user a sad goodbye message, meany!
        $server->disconnect($client->server_clients_index); // Disconnect this client.
        return; // Ends the function
    }




    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,$output); // Send the Client back the String
    SocketServer::socket_write_smart($client->socket,"String? ",""); // Request Another String
}
```

Comment: Why not just kill that PHP process or set up some sort of watchdog process?  I mean, the real thing you'd have to figure out is why the socket server is crashing.